# Can I hack a portion of a HTML page in a Rails Server

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am studying Ruby on Rails and I came across this sentence:

```
= render partial: 'dashboard_empleados' if employee?

= render partial: 'dashboard_admin' if admin?
```

Now, this is pretty straight forward, but I just can stop thinking if it is a way that I can hack the rails server from the outside in order to force it to show me the admin partial.
Does anyone can explain it to me?

Comment: This depends on the implementation of the `admin?` method. In general, the code you are showing is safe to use. If someone has hacked the server and has access to modify the partial ... they wouldn't need to, they've already got access to your server.

Comment: Seems fair enough, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly safe. Rails renders these pages when they're requested, and no user input goes into the `admin?` method.

In general, a method like this can only be abused if some kind of user input is going into it, or if it's using information from elsewhere that has been subject to user interaction. In this case `admin?` is perfectly safe.